# Adding multiple assets to collection with Photo Framework - Objective-C

Tags: ios, objective-c, photosframework

I have the following code:

```
-(void) saveFromLocationsArray: (NSArray*) locations{
[self.photoLib performChanges:^{
    PHAssetChangeRequest *creationRequest;
    NSMutableArray *changesArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    for(int i=0; i<locations.count; i++){
        creationRequest = [PHAssetChangeRequest creationRequestForAssetFromImageAtFileURL:locations[i]];
        [changesArray addObject:[creationRequest placeholderForCreatedAsset]];
    }
    PHAssetCollectionChangeRequest *collectionChangeRequest = [PHAssetCollectionChangeRequest changeRequestForAssetCollection:self.objcAppAlbum];
    [collectionChangeRequest addAssets:changesArray];
} completionHandler:^(BOOL success, NSError *error) {
    if(!success){
        NSLog(@"an error has occured while trying to save pic to library: %@", error);
    }
    else{
        NSLog(@"image was added to album ObjcApp");
    }
}];
```

In a nutshell: I have an array of locations (URLS) of images I've just downloaded, and I'm trying to add them all to the iPhone's photo library. i managed to do so for one image (in a different method) but here it crashes on [collectionChangeRequest addAssets:changesArray], my guess is that the argument fo addAssest is invalid... but i can't figure out why.
this is the working code for one image only:

```
-(void) saveFromLocation: (NSURL*) location{
[self.photoLib performChanges:^{
    PHAssetChangeRequest *creationRequest = [PHAssetChangeRequest creationRequestForAssetFromImageAtFileURL:location];
    PHAssetCollectionChangeRequest *collectionChangeRequest = [PHAssetCollectionChangeRequest changeRequestForAssetCollection:self.objcAppAlbum];
    NSArray *arr = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:[creationRequest placeholderForCreatedAsset], nil];
    [collectionChangeRequest addAssets:arr];
} completionHandler:^(BOOL success, NSError *error) {
    if(!success){
        NSLog(@"an error has occured while trying to save pic to library: %@", error);
    }
    else{
        NSLog(@"image was added to album ObjcApp");
    }
}];
```

}

> error: 2019-03-05 14:26:26.062368 ObjcProject[1026:371314]
>   -[__NSCFString path]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x1740fa880 2019-03-05 14:26:26.063343 ObjcProject[1026:371314] ***
>   Terminating app due to uncaught exception
>   'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSCFString path]:
>   unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x1740fa880'
>   *** First throw call stack: (0x186d3d1b8 0x18577455c 0x186d44268 0x186d41270 0x186c3a80c 0x19276338c 0x192700ee8 0x19275e8c4
>   0x19275edfc 0x1914ae4b8 0x191d49c4c 0x19275e510 0x192738be4
>   0x1914a0ddc 0x1001dd258 0x1001dd218 0x1001eaaec 0x1001e0ce0
>   0x1001eb088 0x1001ece2c 0x1001ecb78 0x185dcf2a0 0x185dced8c)
>   libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type
>   NSException

Comment: Post your error

Comment: sorry, updated.

Comment: Try using weakSelf for objcAppAlbum. And don't use PHAssetChangeRequest *creationRequest; outside your for loop, and see if it helps

Comment: so where should I use PHAssetChangeRequest *creationRequest? I tried with weakSelf but it doesn't seem to fix the problem... pretty sure its something with the arguments... see the difference between the the two methods: [collectionChangeRequest addAssets:changesArray]; [collectionChangeRequest addAssets:arr] , and arr is an array with one object and one , nil;

Comment: Create it inside your for loop. And try creating an NSArray, instead of a mutable one ([NSArray fromArray:yourMutableArray])

Comment: still crashed with those changes, unfortunately